# How to view manpage of apt-secure?

Tags: apt, manpage

I get the message at the end of updating apt:

```
See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

And I just want to know where and what command I need to enter to view this documentation.

Comment: Manpages can be viewed using `man package`, here, `man apt-secure`.

Comment: Or online, here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-secure.8.html